# Como preencher automaticamente um EditText no android

Tags: android

Tenho um aplicativo que calcula o valor total por produto da compra(quantidade x valor unitario do produto).

Queria que o campo **EditText** do **total por produto** fosse preenchido automaticamente depois que os campos de **quantidade** e **valor unitário** fossem preenchidos.

Alguém sabe como fazer com um *EditText* ou *TextView* esse processo automático.

Comment: Poste o código para facilitar a galera ajudar no seu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só adicionar um TextChangedListener no editText quantidade e valor unitario, algo como:

```
quantidade.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //aqui você realiza os calculos que precisa e atribui o resultado
        //ao local desejado
    }
});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Valeuuu Christian Beregula!!!